# PHP ("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ... AND ...")

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to query a table twice/filter a table twice?

For example, I want to filter down the results so that the results I have left show everything from my table where one column is equal to 'MAN' and the other is a time that is greater than '12:00:00'. I have been doing this but it isn't working, as follows:

```php
if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM TBLFlight WHERE IATADep = 'MAN' AND SchDep > '12:00:00';")){
    if($result->num_rows){
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            echo $row->FlightID, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $row->FlightNum, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $row->IATADep , '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $row->IARAArr , '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $row->SchDep , '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $row->SchArr , '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $row->Comments ,'<br />';
        }
        $result->free();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: _How_ isn't this working? White screen? Error message? Wrong data returned? No data returned? What if you try just one of the filters; does that get the right data?

Comment: you see the semi-colon in `'12:00:00';` <<< that's an end of statement character and the rest of your code won't execute. Remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - I get no error it is just blank space

Comment: Is this your whole code? If so add `else { echo 'query failed ;('; }`  at your last `}`.

Comment: looks like legitimate sql - what do you get if you run the query in a gui ( heidi etc ) ?

Comment: I've got part of my money on the semi-colon. That shouldn't be in there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- unless the question was edited I'm not seeing a problem.  It's inside the SQL command string, at the end.

Comment: @James an `if();` is similar to a `while`. I.e.: `while($row = $result->fetch_object());{` being valid syntax and will stop right there. OP might have forgotten to remove it. It's a syntax error for sure though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - you're right, but that semi colon is inside the quotes, so it's part of the SQL string.

Comment: @andrewsi yeah... am sure the OP might've done a bad paste from another piece of code they may have been using. That would have surely thrown an syntax error, had they been checking for errors in their query. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- you're not getting it

Comment: @OP: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php check for errors when testing and make sure your column's type is correct for that time.

Comment: @James I have, see my comment above to Andrew. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are [presumably] comparing a time column (`SchDep`) to a string literal (`'12:00:00'`). MySQL handles this by converting the time to a string, and then comparing both sides of the `<` operator **lexicographically**. Instead, you could explicitly extract the hour and compare the values properly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TBLFlight 
WHERE  IATADep = 'MAN' AND HOUR(SchDep) > 12
```

Comment: The semi-colon here `'12:00:00';")` in an `if` statement; that should be failing also and killing the rest of the process. It would surely kill a process in a `while` anyway. I.e.: `while($row = $result->fetch_object());{` being valid syntax.

Comment: That Semicolon is part of the query-string.